# Exposing internal component of a class in order to prevent writing too much code and impact on performance

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, visibility, signals-slots

Let's say I have a class

```
class B : public class QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  B(QObject* parent=Q_NULLPTR);
signals:
   void signalData(int data);
public slots:
  void slotGetData();
private:
}
```

The `slotGetData()` is triggered externally and basically retrieves some data from somewhere and sends it back using `signalData(int data)`. On the other hand I also have another class

```
class A : public class QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  A(QObject* parent=Q_NULLPTR) {
    // Init B, move to thread, setup timer, connect timer's timeout to B's slotGetData()

    // Connect B to A
    connect(this->B, SIGNAL(signalData(int)), this, SLOT(slotGetData(int)));
  }
signals:
  // Emit signal containing data to another Qt component
  void signalData(int x);
private slots:
  // Connect B::signalData(int x) to this slot and re-emit the data using A::signalData(int x). Don't do anything with the data!
  void slotGetData(int x);
private:
  B* workerObj;
  QThread worker;
  QTimer workerTimer;
}
```

which basically is responsible for instantiating `workerObj`, moving it to `worker` thread and connecting the `workerTimer`'s `timeout()` signal to `B::slotGetData()`.

The purpose of this class is to enable proper integration (multi-threaded) of `B` inside a third-party class that wants to use it for example:

```
class ThirdParty : public class QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  ThirdParty(QObject* parent=Q_NULLPTR) {
    // Init A

    // Connect to B through A
    connect(this->integrationObj, SIGNAL(signalData(int)), this, SLOT(slotGetData(int)));
  }
private slots:
  // Connect A::signalData(int x) to this slot and do something with the x (change UI, whatever)
  void slotGetData(int x);
private:
  A* integrationObj;
}
```

The class `ThirdParty` gains indirect access to specific features of `B` through `A`.

Now the dilemma I'm facing is the following:

- Should I just relay the data signal which comes from `B` through `A` and expose it as a signal of `A` or
- Should I just return a `const` reference to `B` to allow an class which has `A` in it (so that it can use `B`) to directly connect to `B`'s `signalData(int x)`?

In the first case (which I have) I basically have to mirror every single signal `B` wants to offer to the outside inside `A` (by providing the respective private slots in `A` and also signals that are basically the same as `B`'s). Needless to say this leads to having too much of the same stuff and also has some (even if just slight) performance impact since I get 2 signal emissions (from `B` to `A` and then from `A` to whichever other object has `A`) and 2 slot calls (one in `A` to get signal from `B` and one in whichever other object has `A` to get signal from `A`).

The second case seems nice but I fear that I will expose features of `B` which the class containing `A` may not be allowed to have access to

If the second case is implemented I would have something like this (`B` doesn't change):

```
class A : public class QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  A(QObject* parent=Q_NULLPTR);
  const B* getB() const; // Return a reference to B that cannot be changed but can be used to expose B's slots and signals
signals:
private slots:
private:
  B* workerObj;
  QThread worker;
  QTimer workerTimer;
}

class ThirdParty : public class QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  ThirdParty(QObject* parent=Q_NULLPTR) {
    // Init A

    // Connect to B directly!
    connect(this->A->getB(), SIGNAL(signalData(int)), this, SLOT(slotGetData(int)));
  }
private slots:
  // Connect B::signalData(int x) to this slot and do something with the x (change UI, whatever)
  void slotGetData(int x);
private:
  A* integrationObj;
}
```

What should I do here? Sadly there are no **private signals** hence all `B` signals but also all of its public slots will be exposed. If all these are to be used, there is no issue with this degree of exposure but otherwise...not so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*facepalm* I already had the solution in another project of mine. :D I just need to provide a `connectTo(QObject* thirdparty)` inside `A`, which internally connects the `thirdparty` slot only to specific signal of `B` thus not exposing things from `B` that are not meant to be exposed!

Another better solution is to use a signal-to-signal connection (`connect(const QObject *sender, const char *signal, const char *method, Qt::ConnectionType type)`) or use the child-parent relation though in the latter I have to make sure that the parent actually is set. This is also known as signal forwarding and requires 2 signals but no extra slots. Since `A` is visible to `ThirdParty` I can do (`this` here represents `ThirdParty`) `connect(this, SIGNAL(signalFromThirdPartyToB()), this->a, SIGNAL(signalFromAToB()))` to set the forwarding of `ThirdParty` signals to `B` through `A` and then do the actual signal-slot connection between the forwarding signal in `A` to a slot in `B` by calling (`this` here represents `A`) `connect(this, SIGNAL(signalFromAToB()), this->b, SLOT(slotB()))`.

Comment: Signal-slot system is one means of decoupling classes. Using it to tightly couple classes as you do seems counterintuitive. Generally speaking, if classes A and B interoperate but can be decoupled, do decouple them and let their user compose/couple them as appropriate. You can of course have helper functions that factor out common coupling patterns between A and B if you happen to reuse them. Ideally A should not know B's type and vice versa, and they should be buildable in isolation.

Comment: `A` and `B` are tightly coupled except for a very limited set of functions. `A` is the one thing that brings `B` to live and basically is responsible for `ThirdParty` to actually get any data whatsoever. Many of the functions `B` offers are actually not slots but just plain functions that only `A` is supposed to access.